# Footer isn't 100% width

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the footer. First the code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  background: url('../images/bg.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body > #wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 120px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.footer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  //many other div container
</div>

<div class="footer">

  Test.

</div>
```

Now my footer isn't 100% of the width it is exactly: 900 px like the wrapper, why?

In my wrapper are several div containers but they are all closed.

Thank you

Comment: Use `vw`. `.footer { width: 100vw; }`

Comment: When I try your [code in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3hmg0w5/) it works fine, if I understand your requirement correctly (I added a border to the wrapper to make it more obvious). The footer is always 100% the width of the viewable window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width: 100%;` adapts to the width of the parent, since your wrapper is 900px wide, it takes up that space.
I recommend using container classes for your width, something like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            Your header here.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
            Your content here.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            Your footer here.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

.container{
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 30px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `#wrapper`'s width is 900px. So is your `body`'s width. therefore your `.footer` element is 900px as well, since it takes its parent's width... 900px.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put width: 100% on the #wrapper. Because you have 900px width on #wrapper, it stops the footer to take the full width of the screen.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/un97bgfs/).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  background: url('../images/bg.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body > #wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 120px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.footer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  //many other div container
</div>

<div class="footer">

  Test.

</div>
```